# MySQL remove trailing newline characters from a field in a new record to be inserted

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

We would like to remove trailing newline characters from a field in a new record to be inserted into a table in a MySQL DB. For this to work, we replace the newline character with `''`.

We think we need a before insert trigger so we have come up with the following trigger

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER remove_trailing_newline BEFORE INSERT ON memo FOR EACH ROW 
  if new.content like 'Leading text %\n' then
    set new.content = REPLACE(new.content, '\n','' );
  end if;//
delimiter ;
```

However, this is not working and we think the problem lies with having a proper function to replace the newline character. Is anyone experienced with a similar problem?

Comment: What engine are you using?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto We are using InnoDB

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto What difference does it make which engine is used?

Comment: **MyISAM** does not support triggers and stored procedures, but accept them, and then ignores them...

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER remove_trailing_newline 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON memo 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.content = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM NEW.content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, in MySQL 5.7 and 8.0, not in triggers though. I had newlines in a simple SQL SELECT.

The solution is simple - using the HEX function showed me that I have 2 characters at the end of the field CHAR(13) and CHAR(10) - CR and LF so the solution is to replace both characters - ie

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(postcode,'\r',''),'\n','')
```